# Storing history of full/partial tables

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm building a web-application with Django and MySQL (InnoDB) and am currently pondering over how to manage historical changes on various tables.

I wonder if it's efficient to store a lot of rows with NULLS on those rows that didn't change. For example this is a simplistic representation of my products table;

[image]

The `products_history` table has all it's field (except the *FK* and non-logical rows) set to `NULL`, whereas the normal `products` table has `NOT NULL` on all, except `description`.

Now what I had in mind is to push a duplicate of the actual product row and push the change into the `products_history` table. So let's say I have this row in `products`:

```
{600, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 2, 'BS001', NULL, 49.95}
```

and would change the price to `48.50`. So I would push which values has changed, in this case the `base_price` and add a change-row to the history table;

```
{600, THE_date_created_FROM_PRODUCT, NULL, NULL, 49.95}
{600, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, NULL, 48.50}
```

So here on the first modification of a Product it will get 2 rows, and each modification afterwards only one new with the modified fields). After it will update the current `product` row with the new `base_price`.

This approach works for me and is quite effective (as the history table will only be filled with product data if a product get's actual edited for the first time), but I am wondering if it this is efficient by storing all those NULL-values. Would it affect my performance after a while or would the impact not be that great?

Otherwise; I'm curious what would be good approaches to do this in MySQL, or even Django ORM-specific ways.

Comment: The nulls don't really bother me (they don't take up space, as far as I learned).  I've found that a lot of history table design is based on how you're going to use the historical data.  You might want to keep everything in the products table with a start/end date (the active record would not have an end date); or you might have a table with (id,field,orig_value,new_value) where you record fields that were changed.

Comment: A future visitor might find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112314/63644).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to have a temporal table for business time (sometimes called valid time) as history. Basically what you have is a copy of your products table with additional attributes for begin_time and end_time:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_HISTORY
( ...
, BEGIN_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
, END_TIME TIMESTAMP
,    PRIMARY KEY (<key>, BEGIN_TIME) );
```

When you add a product you add a row to the history with BEGIN=now and END=null.

When a product changes you update the row where END=null to END=now, and add a new row as for insert.

When a product is removed update the row where END=null to END=now

All these manipulations of the history table are easily implemented via triggers.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your storing NULL question: [Storing NULL Values / Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage)

When setting up a historical model like such, you really need to pay attention to what the historical data will be used for...as in, will I need this data for historical reporting, trivial lookups, metrics / analysis, corporate data compliance (the list goes on)?

If there is no need for the historical data based off of the above mentioned, then simply do your CRUD up against the base table and add a "modified_at" | "modified_by" etc. field to represent the most recent change and what changed it, i.e. "System", "UserId" etc.

If a historical model is imperative or a business requirement, then extrapolate on the historical table by adding the needed fields that will keep your auditing and serialization at bay, i.e. "modified_at" etc... In addition use MySQL Triggers [MySQL Triggers & Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)

The triggers will allow you to manipulate what data you need / want in history by utilizing snippets of conditionals and the  NEW.* / OLD.* syntax. By doing so you can limit what NULL values you store to the data page based on your individual use cases. Ensure to read up on BEFORE / AFTER trigger actions for data retention reasons.